# I can not to access to my tag by id or classname in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a problem in javascript when I create a html tag with `c#` in `asp.net`.
I can not access my tag by id or classname in javascript.

In C#:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    dx = Convert.ToString(row[col]);
    dy = "<div class='dsearch'>" + dx + "</div>" + dy;
}
```

In Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dsearch').click(function () {
        alert("aaaaaa");
    });
});
```

When I click this tag in web page no reaction, nothing happens. But if I create the tag with html code in a html page it works well.

Comment: Are the elements created via JavaScript after the page has loaded?

Comment: You can try live event - `$(document).on('click', '.dsearch', function() {})`

Comment: Have you viewed your web page source and verified that the tag was there?  If it was created using a web control, the client ID may be different than the ID you set for the ASP.NET control.

Comment: @CMKanode he's trying to access to the control by `ClassName`, the problem here is that, it is a dynamic control, and the dynamic controls need to call the onclick like @user3388636 said.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.dsearch', function() {}) is To work well. 
Thank you

Comment: Please try to call javascript from code behind after creating this dynamic tag . you can call method `page.registerstartupscript` and then put javascript code inside it.make sure register div click event not on  $(document).ready....

Comment: @Freak_Droid, the OP did state "by id or classname", and I was only addressing the id part.  Though, thank you for pointing it out.  Sometimes it is easy to latch onto one part and ignore the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dynamically generating and inserting the HTML into the DOM my guess is the event listener never got attached.  JQuery does have the on() method (formally the live() method in older versions).  Rewrite the click event listener like so and it should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dsearch', function (e) {
    // past click event code
});
```